# Exposing server to external world

Tags: ip, network-access

In my work network I have many machines (local and external). I mean that some machines expose to world website of company, another one exposes repository and so on.  There are a lot of only local machines.

I have some spring-boot server.

What should I do in order to expose server to external world on machine:

- local machine
- external machine (so for example machine which exposes website or repository) ?

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information. For example, a detailed description of how the network is connected, and the network device models and configurations. Keep in mind that host/server/VM configurations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the term 'spring-boot server' but if you're asking the basic question of 'How do I expose server X through my firewall?', you should really investigate your firewall configuration to determine how to allow inbound traffic from the external IP (generally done with NAT or MIP/VIP setups).

If you're asking security related questions like 'How do I securely expose server X through my firewall?' then I would suggest you investigate what your application actually requires for external access (does it need just port 80, 8080, or 443 etc..) and then decide if you want to put that application directly accessible or through a load balancer or reverse proxy.

Really, as @haskell mentioned, you need to provide quite a bit more information before someone can give you any detailed answer.